# How to add two numbers as a string

Tags: c, string

I have to read from standard input two numbers as strings, in C. How can I print their sum as a string too? I have:

```
char a[10],b[10];
printf("enter the two numbers");
scanf("%s%s",&a,&b);
char sum[20];
sum=?
```

A little tip,please?
Thank you!

Comment: `snprintf(sum,........);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chars` are 8-bit binary numbers, just like smaller `ints`.  We must interpret them to give them meaning as letters.

Your computer probably uses the ASCII standard.  In ASCII, the `char` value representing the character `0` does not actually have the numerical value 0.  It's 48.  Fortunately, the numbers are all consecutive, so `1` is 49, etc.

```
char zero = '0';
printf("%d\n", zero);
char one = '1';
printf("%d\n", one);

> 48
> 49
```

(Note that the `%d` format flag in `printf` means "interpret as an integer".)

Since `chars` are numbers, we can do math with them.

```
char one = '1';
int one_num = one - '0';
printf("%d\n", one_num);

> 1
```

Now, you can implement the addition with decimal digits and carrying just like you'd do on paper.

Answer (score 3):

Just do it like in elementary school

Let's say the input was "...69 + ...63"

```
9 + 3     = 2 and 1 to go
6 + 6 + 1 = 3 and 1 to go
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this with programming just as you would do it on paper. Make small steps, and make explicit every little step that we do on paper without noticing.

```
    00111
 ---------
     12345
 123456789
 ---------
 123469134
```

- Notice different lengths. You'll need separate vars to hold that info. You'll need to find out the two lengths - either use a standard function, or write your own: strings end with a binary `0`.
- Notice how we go backwards while we add. You'll have to maintain two indices to access the two strings (arrays of chars).
- Notice how we carry over the high digit of the addition `5+9=14`. You'll need to maintain that in another variable.

Use loops. After you've added, you will need to know the total length, and move it to the left edge. Because we don't know in advance what length we'll get, you'll start writing down the answer from the right edge of your `sum` array. Think, how and what can you improve about this.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is prohibited to do so, then I would approach as the following:

- Convert the input string(s) to numbers. I would try[`strtol()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/).
- Add the numbers
- Convert the sum from number to string. I would try[`snprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/).

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings into numbers using `atoi`, then add them together, and then print the sum using a print function like printf. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: Better `strtol()` than the function you suggested. `strtol()` is well behaved in presence of 'stupid' input.

Comment: this is one of the problems that i need to prepare for school. and it is not allowed to convert them into integer . thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, so you're asking us to do your homework. That's horrible. If this is for school and you can't use `atoi`, they probably want to teach you about ascii encodings, look into that.

Comment: @Madalina Well, you *have* to convert it to numeric value *somewhere*, unless you use the brute force approach.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai you can add digit by digit.

Comment: The OP asked only for "little tip,please", what's so horrible about that? Please don't scare away the newbies.

Comment: @WillNess That is still converting to numeric value.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai you really don't see a difference between 2^31-1 and 10?

Comment: @Deidara-senpai more importantly, converting by digits has no chance of overflow - that is the main reason.

Comment: @WillNess *I* know the difference between the two. The brute force "idea" was just to set the OP thinking if he really understands the implications of "not allowed to convert to integer". There is no way I would recommend using brute force.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai what do you mean by the brute force approach? I took it to mean digit-by-digit summation, and I think it is the only way to add numbers as strings - strings can be very long, after all. That is why they forbid the plain atoi() conversion, is my understanding.